# how I can get return code of org.gnome.SessionManager.CanShutsown in JS?

Tags: javascript, gnome, dbus

I want to check if shutdown is available to the current user( in javascript, not shell command).
     I have try this command in shell:

```
 dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.CanShutdown
```

I got the return message"boolen true"

In gnome's documentaion, I can see this line: CanShutdown (out 'b' is_available), but I don't know how to use outsignatue in js.

Can anyone tell me how to do? Or some other documentions. THANK YOU!

Comment: which javascript client are you using?

Comment: sorry, I'm very new to js,  and  not sure which one I'm using.  I'm reading source code about cinnamon.  reboot will fail in such situation : If there are multi-users logging, admin user log out first,  there are only normal users left, if one of these users reboot system in cinnamon's user applet, it will fail. I want to check canshutdown before reboot, but now I find it's unuseful.